# PHP ArrayObject: Array was modified outside object and internal position is no longer valid

Tags: php, arrayobject

I'm trying to create a kind of flash-message class that will "flush" messages when they are fetched the first time. So not on the next HTTP request if, for example, forwarded from one controller action to another (of the same HTTP request)

Here is my class design:

```
<?php
namespace MartynBiz;

/**
 * Flash messages. Slight variation in that this will store a message until it
 * is accessed - whether that is a next http request, or same request. Simply
 * when get method is called the message is wiped from session.
 * TODO move this to martynbiz\php-flash
 */
class Flash
{
    /**
     * Message storage
     *
     * @var ArrayObject
     */
    protected $storage;

    /**
     * @param string $storage Name to store messages in session
     */
    public function __construct($storage=null)
    {
        // if storage is not defined, create ArrayObject (not persistent)
        if (is_null($storage)) {
            $storage = new \ArrayObject();
        }

        $this->storage = $storage;
    }

    /**
     * Add flash message
     *
     * @param string $key The key to store the message under
     * @param string $message Message to show on next request
     */
    public function addMessage($key, $message)
    {
        // create entry in the session
        $this->storage[$key] = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get flash messages, and reset storage
     * @return array Messages to show for current request
     */
    public function flushMessages()
    {
        $messages = $this->storage->getArrayCopy();

        // clear storage items
        foreach ($this->storage as $key => $value) {
            unset($this->storage[$key]);
        }

        return $messages;
    }
}
```

I've written some PHPUnit tests that also demonstrate how the Flash class might be used:

```
<?php

// TODO test with an ArrayAccess/Object $storage passed in

use MartynBiz\Flash;
use Zend\Session\Container;

class FlashTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    protected $flash;

    public function testInstantiation()
    {
        $flash = new Flash();

        $this->assertTrue($flash instanceof Flash);
    }

    public function testGettingSetting()
    {
        $flash = new Flash();

        $flash->addMessage('key1', 'value1');
        $flash->addMessage('key2', 'value2');
        $flash->addMessage('key2', 'value3');

        $expected = array(
            'key1' => 'value1',
            'key2' => 'value3',
        );

        // assert first time to access messages
        $messages = $flash->flushMessages();
        $this->assertEquals($expected, $messages);

        // assert messages have been cleared
        $messages = $flash->flushMessages();
        $this->assertEquals(array(), $messages);
    }

    public function testCustomStorage()
    {
        $container = new Container('mycontainer');
        $flash = new Flash($container);

        $flash->addMessage('key1', 'value1');

        $expected = array(
            'key1' => 'value1',
        );

        // assert first time to access messages
        $messages = $flash->flushMessages();
        $this->assertEquals($expected, $messages);

        // assert messages have been cleared
        $messages = $flash->flushMessages();
        $this->assertEquals(array(), $messages);
    }
}
```

You can see that I'm also passing in a custom $storage (Zend session container instance) which is one option I'd like. These tests appear to pass, however I get the following error on the other ones and I don't really understand what the issue is:

```
$ ./vendor/bin/phpunit tests/library/FlashTest.php 1
PHPUnit 4.8.21-4-g7f07877 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

.E.

Time: 68 ms, Memory: 4.50Mb

There was 1 error:

1) FlashTest::testGettingSetting
MartynBiz\Flash::flushMessages(): ArrayIterator::next(): Array was modified outside object and internal position is no longer valid

/var/www/crsrc-slimmvc/app/library/MartynBiz/Flash/Flash.php:53
/var/www/crsrc-slimmvc/tests/library/FlashTest.php:33

FAILURES!
Tests: 3, Assertions: 3, Errors: 1.
```

I've searched around for this error and tried a few alternatives (e.g. $this->storage->getIterator() ) but still I get the same error. Any ideas where I'm going wrong? I guess I'm a little new to ArrayObject.

Comment: Have you tried `offsetUnset` method?
http://php.net/manual/en/arrayobject.offsetunset.php

I think this can help you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Shouldn't that method be automatically invoked when I use `unset`?

Comment: Actually you can't use standard array methods on `ArrayObject` as stated in the docs. So I suspect it'll not work and creating problems. You can see examples in the comments on the link.

Comment: Using `if ($storage instanceof ArrayObject) {...` it seems I was able to loop through `foreach(get_object_vars($storage) as $key => $value) {...` which worked for the ArrayObject. For the other type, I used standard `foreach($storage as $key => $value) {...`. My tests all pass now at least :)